# Disable all months & days in textbox except selected month in another textbox in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have 2 textbox named as LeaveFrom & LeaveTo.In (Leavefrom)textbox i want to put a date through JQuery datepicker but In (Leaveto)textbox i want to select date of that month only  selected by (Leavefrom)textbox by disabling next & Previous month & that to from selected date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtDate').datepicker({
showAnim: 'slide',
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
});
$("#txtToDate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+60D",
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: plz show what u tried instead of telling what u want to accomplish

Comment: What have you tried? Can you elaborate your question and provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/C7ukS/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    today = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();

    $('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#from').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1d",
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+2M",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        required: true,
        showOn: "focus",
    });

    $('#from').change(function () {
        var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
        var date_diff = Math.ceil((from.getTime() - Date.parse(today)) / 86400000);
        date_diff = date_diff + 'd';
        $('#to').val('').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            minDate: date_diff,
            changeMonth: false,
            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
            stepMonths: 0,
        });

    });
});
```

in var `today` today's date is stored in format `August 14 2013`

input with id `from` is assigned  datepicker with date stating from tomorrow to next 3 months

input with id `to` is disabled until the user selects the date in the input with id `from`

when date is changed in the input with id `from` var `date_diff` is calculated the difference between current date and the date selected in the input with id `from` and the variable `date_diff` is passed to the `minDate` option in the input with id `to` and it is enabled.

`stepMonths: 0` disables changing of month so user has to select date within that month only.